# Change SharedPreferences Value From Fragment Failed

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment with a logout button inside.
I put a listener for that button that will change the login status to `FALSE`. However, when the button is clicked, the `App Unfortunately Closed`.

What's wrong?

Here's the code on the listener

```
SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager;
sharedPrefManager.saveSPBoolean(SharedPrefManager.SP_SUDAH_LOGIN, false);
```

And here's the `SharedPrefManager.java` class

````
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class SharedPrefManager {
    public static final String SP_MAHASISWA_APP = "spMahasiswaApp";

    public static final String SP_NAMA = "spNama";
    public static final String SP_EMAIL = "spEmail";

    public static final String SP_SUDAH_LOGIN = "spSudahLogin";

    SharedPreferences sp;
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor;

    public SharedPrefManager(Context context){
        sp = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_MAHASISWA_APP, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        spEditor = sp.edit();
    }

    public void saveSPString(String keySP, String value){
        spEditor.putString(keySP, value);
        spEditor.commit();
    }

    public void saveSPInt(String keySP, int value){
        spEditor.putInt(keySP, value);
        spEditor.commit();
    }

    public void saveSPBoolean(String keySP, boolean value){
        spEditor.putBoolean(keySP, value);
        spEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getSPNama(){
        return sp.getString(SP_NAMA, "");
    }

    public String getSPEmail(){
        return sp.getString(SP_EMAIL, "");
    }

    public Boolean getSPSudahLogin(){
        return sp.getBoolean(SP_SUDAH_LOGIN, false);
    }
}```
````

Comment: what is the error log you got?

Comment: @Zain logcat shows nothing

Comment: you may debug your code to see which line is causing this

Comment: `logcat shows nothing` that's quite unlikely. I'd rather assume that you somehow filter logcat output and simply do not see the crash log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably getting null pointer exception which is causing crash in your app, you need to initialize your shared preferences class and the use that object as:

```
SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager (getContext());
sharedPrefManager.saveSPBoolean(SharedPrefManager.SP_SUDAH_LOGIN, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use **singleton design pattern** rather than every time create an object of the same class. `Singleton design pattern` restricts the `instantiation` of a class to one `single instance`.

You can create a **singleton class** for **SharedPreference** and then you can access it from any `activity` or `fragment` you want.

Example

```
public class SharedPrefManager{
  private static SessionManager jInstance;
  private final SharedPreferences prefs;
  private final SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

  // private constructor to force use of 
  // getInstance() to create Singleton object 
  private SharedPrefManager(Context context) {
      prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Your_Preference_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      editor = prefs.edit();
  }

  // create the instance when it is accessed for the first time
  public static synchronized SharedPrefManager getInstance(Context context) {
      if (jInstance != null) {
          return jInstance;
      } else {
          jInstance = new SharedPrefManager(context);
          return jInstance;
      }
  }

  // for changing logged in status
  public void isLoggedIn(boolean loginStatus){
      editor.putString("is_loggedin",loginStatus);
      editor.apply();
  }

  // for checking logged in status
  public boolean isLoggedIn(){
      return prefs.getBoolean("is_loggedin",false);
  }
}
```

Now you can user `SharedPrefManager` from your fragment like below.

```
SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context).isLoggedIn(false); // change login status
boolean isUserLoggedIn = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context).isLoggedIn(); // check login status.
```